# Why is my Realm Kotlin Generics workaround not working as expected?

Tags: generics, kotlin, realm

I know that Realm doesn't yet support Generics directly. I have been trying to come up with a workaround as it will reduce duplicate code immensely in my project. (I have many repos which extend base repo and a lot of functions which only differ by RealmObject extended type)

I have got a reasonably good solution working:

```
open class BaseRepository(private val realm: Realm) {

    fun <T : RealmModel> get(ofType: Class<T>, id: Long): T? {
        return realm.where(ofType).equalTo("id", id).findFirst()
    }  
}
```

This can be called by my repositories which inherit from BaseRepository like so:

```
customRepository.get(CustomType::class.java, id)
```

I tried to improve this further by passing the class type in the constructor instead of the function param:

```
open class BaseRepository<T : RealmModel?>(private val realm: Realm, private val ofType: Class<T>) {

    fun <T : RealmModel> get(id: Long): T? {
        return realm.where(ofType).equalTo("id", id).findFirst()
    }
}
```

The above has the following compile time error:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: T#1 (type parameter of com.acme.data.repository.BaseRepository.get)?
Found:    T#2 (type parameter of com.acme.data.repository.BaseRepository)?
```

I have made various attempts to get this working but as yet I am unsuccessful.

Questions:

1. Why can't I pass the ofType: Class in the constructor param but I can in the function param?
2. Does anyone know how to fix it?
3. Is there any issue, Realm or otherwise, with what I am doing as it does seem to work and all my tests still pass?
4. Has anyone got a better solution for this, for example using kotlin extension methods?

Thanks,
Paul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you pass the class to the superclass, then you no longer need to use template parameter for your function.

```
open class BaseRepository<T : RealmModel>(private val realm: Realm, private val ofType: Class<T>) {

    fun get(id: Long): T? =
        realm.where(ofType).equalTo("id", id).findFirst()
}
```

An interesting tidbit is that with Kotlin, you could reduce the `::class.java` using `inline <reified T>`.

```
open class BaseRepository(private val realm: Realm) {

    inline fun <reified T : RealmModel> get(id: Long): T? =
        realm.where(T::class.java).equalTo("id", id).findFirst()
}
```

Or if you are using a newer version of Realm (4.3.1+), then you could change this to

```
import io.realm.kotlin.where

open class BaseRepository(private val realm: Realm) {

    inline fun <reified T : RealmModel> get(id: Long): T? =
        realm.where<T>().equalTo("id", id).findFirst()
}
```

I'm just throwing ideas at you but you could technically make this into an extension function

```
inline fun <reified T : RealmModel> Realm.get(id: Long): T? =
    where<T>().equalTo("id", id).findFirst()
```

Now you could do

```
val dog = realm.get<Dog>(12L)
```

Comment: This is awesome thanks. I went with the first suggestion as it allows me to specify the ClassType only once during Repository construction and I can just call repo.get(12L) all over my codebase and the type is known based on the specific repository without the need for me to <Dog> it at point of call. I tried to reduce the "::class.java" as suggested but got some errors with this so I will play around with it. This has more than answered my question thanks again!